# How to solve this issue with CTE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursion, common-table-expression

I have a table that links jobs together:

```
JobToJob
(
   JobToJobId int 
   SourceJobId int
   DestinationJobId int 
)
```

A Job can have multiple Destination Jobs (i.e. more than 1 JobToJob record), but only 1 source job. So this creates a tree structure. A root record is defined as one that has no DestinationJobId entries on any other record.

The requirement I have is to retrieve the entire tree for a supplied Job ID. I've split this into two parts:

1. Locate the root job for a given job id
2. retrieve all the leaves for the root job id.

I've had a go at trying this in using a recursive CTE, but I'm not getting anywhere. I'm aware that I could probably do this by using a stored procedure, but I'm trying to avoid doing that as they tend to slow things down.

Has anyone with more recursive CTE experience than me got any suggestions as to the best way to approach this?

Cheers,

Rob

Comment: If job can have only one source job, then I think better database design will be create a field `SourceJobID` in table `Job`. then create two CTE(one for getting all source jobs(up)) and second formgetting all destination jobs(down) after just `UNION`that two CTE...

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a legacy system and that's not an option in this case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you have a Jobs table.

```
declare @JobId int
;with getAscendants( job, parent, inverseDepth)
as
(
  select jj.DestinationJobId, jj.SourceJobId, 1
  from JobToJob jj 
  where jj.DestinationJobId = @JobId

  union all

  select jj.DestinationJobId, jj.SourceJobId, inverseDepth + 1
  from getAscendants
  join JobToJob jj on jj.DestinationJobId = getAscendants.parent
)
,rootFinder( job)
as
(
  select j.JobId
  from Jobs j
  where j.JobId = coalesce
  (
    (
      select top 1 parent from getAscendants order by inverseDepth desc
    )
    , @JobId
  )
)
,getDescendants( job, parent)
as
(
  select j.JobId, null
  from Jobs j
  cross apply rootFinder 
  where j.JobId = rootFinder.job

  union all

  select jj.DestinationJobId, jj.SourceJobId 
  from getDescendants
  join JobToJob jj on jj.SourceJobId = getDescendants.job
) 
select * from getDescendants
```

Comment: That answer was so precise that I don't need to change it in any way - thank you very much! Oh, and I do have a Jobs table...!

Answer (score 0):

You use the term "leaves", which means jobs that have no destinations (as opposed to intermediate nodes in the tree).

Here is one approach.  Start with all the leaves, then climb up the tree attaching all the nodes they are under.  Then select the ones that belong to the job you are interested in:

```
with cte as (
      select DestinationJobId as JobId, DestinationJobId as parent, 1 as level
      from jobs2jobs jj
      where DestinationJobId not in (select SourceJobId from jobs2jobs)
      union all
      select cte.JobId, jj.SourceJobId, level + 1
      from cte
           jobs2jobs jj
           on cte.Parent = jj.DestinationJobId
    )
select *
from cte
where parent = @YourJobId;
```